# Mysterious C++/CLI managed/unmanaged Error with Eigen

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, command-line-interface, eigen

I'm working with an existing Visual Studio 2010 project, where I'm now supposed to add new functionality (Eigen and Point Cloud Library) into an existing method (let's call it `foo()`). I now that the project is using C++/CLI somehow. I have to admit I have no clue about C++/CLI, just read a little bit about it. However the class where `foo()` is declared and defined seems to be a regular C++ class, no `ref` or any other CLI identifier. But within `foo()` Handles (`var^`) are used. So I'm not quite sure if `foo()` is a managed function!? I can add pretty much regular C++ code to this function, but now I started with Eigen and PCL and a discovered some mysterious errors. For example, when I'm declaring this:

```
 Eigen::Matrix3f m;
```

Everythings working fine. But when I'm doing this:

```
 Eigen::Matrix4f m;
```

I get the following errors:

```
error C2711: 'fooclass::foo' : this functon cannot be compiled as managed, consider using #pragma unmanaged 
error C3821: 'void fooclass::foo(void)': managed type or function cannot be used in an unmanaged function
```

So it is working with 3f but not with 4f! That is so strange and it's just one example. I can not recognize any pattern. In my understanding VS somehow thinks that `Matrix4f` is a managed function.

I would appreciate any tip! I don't even know where to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know anything about CLI, but the only significant difference between Matrix3f and Matrix4f is that the second is vectorized and internally its data is requested to be aligned with `__declspec(align(16))`.

Comment: Alright, then one solution is to disable static alignment by defining EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY before any Eigen's header. This also disable vectorization for Matrix4f and the likes.

Comment: EIGEN_DONT_ALIGN_STATICALLY does the trick! It is working now. Thanks.